# What's the meaning of `2097184` in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I use below code to create a empty matrix:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10, 11, 12]])

print(x)

y =np.empty_like(x)

print(y)
# I get below data:
[[2097184 2097184 2097184]
 [2097184 2097184 2097184]
 [2097184 2097184 2097184]
 [2097184 2097184 2097184]]
```

why the 2097184 stand for empty?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty_like.html

Comment: WHen you use `empty_like`, the contents are uninitialized. So they can be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't stand for anything. From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty_like.html):

> This function does not initialize the returned array; to do that use `zeros_like` or `ones_like` instead. It may be marginally faster than the functions that do set the array values.

So the contents of the array are whatever happens to be in the memory that it used for it. In this case, it was a bunch of `2097184` values. The next time you try it you'll probably get something different.

You use this when you don't care what's in the array, because you're going to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

The `empty_like` method does not initialize the array (that's why it's very faster than `zeros_like` and `ones_like`), so the shape of the array is exactly the same as `x`, but the values are uninitialized and actually are almost random values from the memory place allocated to the array.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, it's just a more efficient alternative to `zeros_like` or `ones_like`:

```
%%timeit
np.zeros_like(x)
>>> 18.4 µs ± 2.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
np.ones_like(x)
>>> 14.1 µs ± 205 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
np.empty_like(x)
>>> 2.09 µs ± 62.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```